# Understanding OO JavaScript with a simple scenario

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, inheritance, prototypal-class-design

Coming from a Java kind of OOP, I miss a lot of things in JavaScript. I am working on a Node.Js project, and I would like to use an OO approach.

Looking around and asking in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188083/javascript-oop-in-nodejs-how) I came up with this example scenario ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eS7LE/5/)).

```
function inheritPrototype(childObject, parentObject) {
    var copyOfParent = Object.create(parentObject.prototype)
    copyOfParent.constructor = childObject
    childObject.prototype = copyOfParent
}

//example
function Canvas (id) {
    this.id = id
    this.shapes = {} //instead of array?
    console.log("Canvas constructor called "+id)
}
Canvas.prototype = {
    constructor: Canvas
    , getId: function() {
        return this.id
    }
    , getShape: function(shapeId) {
        return this.shapes[shapeId]
    }
    , getShapes: function() {
        return this.shapes
    }
    , addShape: function (shape)  {
        this.shapes[shape.getId()] = shape
    }
    , removeShape: function (shapeId)  {
        var shape = this.shapes[shapeId]
        if (shape)
            delete this.shapes[shapeId]
        return shape
    }
}

function Shape(id) {
    this.id = id
    this.size = { width: 0, height: 0 }
    console.log("Shape constructor called "+id)
}
Shape.prototype = {
    constructor: Shape
    , getId: function() {
        return this.id
    }
    , getSize: function() {
        return this.size
    }
    , setSize: function (size)  {
        this.size = size
    }
}

//inheritance
function Square(id, otherSuff) {
    Shape.prototype.constructor.apply( this, arguments );
    this.stuff = otherSuff
    console.log("Square constructor called "+id)
}
inheritPrototype(Square, Shape)
Square.prototype.getSize = function() { //override
    return this.size.width
}

function ComplexShape(id) {
    Shape.prototype.constructor.apply( this, arguments );
    this.frame = null
    console.log("ComplexShape constructor called "+id)
}
inheritPrototype(ComplexShape, Shape)
ComplexShape.prototype.getFrame = function() {
    return this.frame
}
ComplexShape.prototype.setFrame = function(frame) {
    this.frame = frame
}

function Frame(id) {
    this.id = id
    this.length = 0
}
Frame.prototype = {
    constructor: Frame
    , getId: function() {
        return this.id
    }
    , getLength: function() {
        return this.length
    }
    , setLength: function (length)  {
        this.length = length
    }
}

/////run
var aCanvas = new Canvas("c1")
var anotherCanvas = new Canvas("c2")
console.log("aCanvas: "+ aCanvas.getId())

var aSquare = new Square("s1", {})
aSquare.setSize({ width: 100, height: 100})
console.log("square overridden size: "+aSquare.getSize())

var aComplexShape = new ComplexShape("supercomplex")
var aFrame = new Frame("f1")
aComplexShape.setFrame(aFrame)
console.log(aComplexShape.getFrame())

aCanvas.addShape(aSquare)
aCanvas.addShape(aComplexShape)
console.log("Shapes in aCanvas: "+Object.keys(aCanvas.getShapes()).length)

anotherCanvas.addShape(aCanvas.removeShape("supercomplex"))
console.log("Shapes in aCanvas: "+Object.keys(aCanvas.getShapes()).length)
console.log("Shapes in anotherCanvas: "+Object.keys(anotherCanvas.getShapes()).length)

console.log(aSquare instanceof Shape)
console.log(aComplexShape instanceof Shape)
```

Is this approach correct (best practices)? Should I do something differently?

The idea would be then to create a js file for each class and use `module.exports`.. in Node.Js I will also use Mongoose to store the objects into a database, I guess I will need a way to translate my objects into Mongoose Models and back..

**EDIT:** how would one implement private methods used internally?

Comment: Like I showed in my answer, you can prefix a method or field with an underscore to communicate that this is an internal method or field, and it should not be accessed directly.

Comment: As per the SO question : There is nothing really specific about OO JS in node.js. There is just OO JS. Your question is about translating Java OOP techniques to JS, which is just not right. I think it better you spent the same time/energy in learning how JS's prototype-based model works, and how you can use it to your advantage.

Comment: @tomdemuyt But I am not. I just stated that I am coming from a Java background -- it is not my intention to use Java style OO in JS. 

However, I can only work with what I know: hence the question, how to do OO in JS?

Comment: @fusio btw can you specify what you miss from Java object model?

Comment: I miss a clear and well defined structure (Class, Instance, Field, Method, inheritance, yada yada). Today I learned a lot about OO JS (until now I only used it "functional", with the exception of jquery I guess). When I think OO I imagine Java classes.. even after this I still miss having a Class with all its methods declared inside, with proper private methods/fields etc..

Comment: @fusio in e.g. browser js you do need a wrapper IIFE where you will define everything "about a Class" inside somewhere :) But this will cause additional level of indentation for everything and is not needed in node js because node.js automatically adds the wrapper.

Comment: I know I'm a tad late to the game, but Mozilla Developer Network has a nice intro to OO JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript. After that, check out [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Answer (score 5):

### Pretty good code.

From an OOP perspective, this is exactly right. From a formatting perspective, this is almost flawless. I hardly have anything to say about this code, but I see very little that I would change.

The only issue that I see is an irregular formatting choice. These commas:

```
Shape.prototype = {
    constructor: Shape
    , getId: function() {
        return this.id
    }
    , getSize: function() {
        return this.size
    }
    , setSize: function (size)  {
        this.size = size
    }
}
```

should be like this:

```
Shape.prototype = {
    constructor: Shape,
    getId: function () {
         return this.id
    },
    getSize: function () {
         return this.size
    },
    setSize: function (size)  {
        this.size = size
    }
};
```

### [Oh and you need to read this world-changing answer about OO practices in JS.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180585/are-there-any-oo-principles-that-are-practically-applicable-for-javascript)

Be sure to press B while reading that, because if not, you'll evolve into a legendary OOP developer.

Comment: comma first style.. I am still undecided if I like it or not, working with the classic style atm ;)

Comment: @fusio That is of course, perfectly ok. It's good to know the conventional practice though in case you decide to work on a group project.